# How to find the absolute maximum and minimum for $f(x,y)=2x^{2}-4x+y^{2}-4y+1$ with a given closed and bounded $D$ region?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Problem:**

Find the absolute maximum and minimum for the smooth function $f(x,y)=2x^{2}-4x+y^{2}-4y+1$ defined on the closed and bounded set $D$. In this case $D$ is the closed region of the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,2)$ and $(1,2)$.

**Solution**:

The first I did was find the functions which defined each edge of the triangle: $(x,2)$, $(x,2x)$ and $(0,y)$:

[image: D region]

But I don't know how to proceed to find the absolute maximum and minimum. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Let's see. First we need to compute the points where the partial derivatives of the function are zero. The partial derivatives are:
$$
d f(x,y) = (4x-4, 2y - 4)
$$
Which is the zero vector when $x=1$ and $y=2$.

To see whether this point is a maximum, a minimum or a saddle point we can compute the Hessian matrix of second derivatives.

$$
H_f =  
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
4 & 0 \\
0 & 2 
\end{array} \right)
$$
As $H_f$ is definite positive, we conclude that there is a local minimum in $x=1$, $y=2$.

Now we have to study the boundary region for maximum and minimums.

Using the functions that you worked out to define the edges of the triangle, we can evaluate the function there.
$$
f_1(x)=f(x,2)=2x^2-4x-3\\
f_2(x)=f(0,y)=y^2-4y+1\\
f_3(x)=f(x,2x)=6x^2-12x+1
$$
Find the maximum and minimums of this functions in the area which falls within the region of interest and you will have found every local maximum and minimum.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is part of the work.  It comes into play in step 2 below.

Step one: check out the partial derivatives.

$f_x (x,y) = 0$ and $f_y(x,y) = 0$

Is this a max a min or a saddle?

Step 2:
check the border.

Using the what you have worked out above:

$f(0,y) = y^2 - 4y + 1\\
f(x,2x) = 2x^2 -4x + 4x^2 - 8x + 1\\
f(x,2) = 2x^2 -4x + K$

You get to find $K.$

Use techniques of single variable calculus to find extrema.

Finally:
check the corners.

One parting thought:
$f(x,y) = 2(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 + K$

This is a paraboloid.  You should be able to find the max min above this region "by inspection."

Answer (score 1):

$$
f(x,y)=2x^2-4x+y^2-4y+1
$$
Formulate system of partial derivatives
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=4x-4=0\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2y-4=0
\end{cases}\to
\begin{cases}
x=1\\
y=2
\end{cases}
$$
This solution gives us extremum, which can be global minimum/maximum, but not necessary. We have to check boundaries. Express them as follows:
$$
C_1=\{x=0,0\le y\le 2\},\quad C_2=\{0\le x\le 1,y=2 \},\quad C_3=\{0\le x\le 1,y=2x\}
$$
Notice, that equations in the system above are independent, hence for $C_1$ and $C_2$ we will get the same valus of $y$ and $x$ respectively.

$C_1: (0,2),\quad C_2:(1,2),$

$C_3:$

$$
f(x,2x)=2x^2-4x+4x^2-8x+1=6x^2-12x+1\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=12x-12=0\to x=1\to y=2
$$
From $C_3$ we get point, which we already obtained previously.
Only thing left is to consider edges, in this case it means extend set of points by $(0,0)$. Now calculate $f(x,y)$:

$$
f(0,0)=1\\
f(0,2)=-3\\
f(1,2)=-5
$$
Hence, $(0,0)$ is global maximum and $(1,2)$ is global minimum.

Comment: how did you got $C_{1}:(0,2)$ and $C_{2}:(1,2)$?

Comment: One coordinate for each of $C_1$ and $C_2$ is fixed. Respectively: $x=0$ for $C_1$ and $y=2$ for $C_2$ (it comes from expressions of boundary lines). Another coordinate can be found by plugging fixed one in initial equation of $f$ and looking on derivative over coordinate which left.